# Shell script - how to extract from line

Tags: shell, unix, awk

Hi please help me to find only numbers. My file have only one line data as below:

```
53-Brand|5556-Color Family|10984-Fit|10313-Combo
```

Looking for output
53, 5556, 10984, 10313

Thanks

---

I tried

```
awk -F',' '{print $2}' /cat_formula       > 1
    53-Brand|5556-Color Family|10984-Fit|10313-Combo

awk -F'|' '{print $1}{print $2}{print $3}{print $4}' 1 >2
    53-Brand
5556-Color Family
10984-Fit
10313-Combo


awk -F'-' '{print $1}' 2
    53
5556
10984
10313
```

But looking in one command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sed is your friend:

```
echo $VALUE | sed -e 's/[^(0-9|)]//g' | sed -e 's/|/, /g'
```

where `VALUE` variable contains your input string.

**Input**: `53-Brand|5556-Color Family|10984-Fit|10313-Combo`

**Output**: `53, 5556, 10984, 10313`

Answer (score 3):

`grep -oP "\d+" filename`

Output:

```
53
5556
10984
10313
```

brief explanation:

`-P` : tells it's a perl regexp
`\d+`: to match just numbers
`-o` : to capture just matched numbers

Comment: That's *Unnecessary Use Of cat* for the uninitiated (or simply *UUOc*).

Comment: Well guys, thanks.  But my motive is to use pipe here and separate grep logic from input source to make it clear enough that if they are reading from other process (say `tail`) then grep simply needs to be piped like this. No doubt the same could be written as  `grep -oP "\d+" filename`.

Comment: Yes, the UUOc is somewhat tongue-in-cheek, notice there were no dings for it. But it does speak loudly about your thought process. So any time you find yourself doing `cat foo` and you are not *concatenating* foo with something else, then you are probably committing a UUOc `:)`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: I have edited as per suggestion. If in the original question it was mentioned that the input file has GBs in size then I would have fed the file directly to the grep in the first step to avoid unnecessary CPU and memory utilisation.

Answer (score 2):

Two approaches:

-- with ***grep***:

```
grep -o '[[:digit:]]\+' file
```

---

-- with ***gawk***:

```
awk -v FPAT='[0-9]+' '{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) print $i }' file
```

---

The output (for both approaches):

```
53
5556
10984
10313
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering your Input_file is same as sample shown. Then try following awk once.

```
awk  -F'[-|]' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if(i%2!=0){val=val?val "," $i:$i}};print val;val=""}'  Input_file
```

**Explanation:** Making - and | as field separators then traversing through all the fields one by one and checking if any field is on ODD position then concatenating it's value to variable named val and out of loop printing it's value and nullifying it.

**EDIT:**  Adding one more solution if Input_file is same as shown sample.

```
awk '{gsub(/-[a-zA-Z]+\||-[a-zA-Z]+ [a-zA-Z]+\|/,",");sub(/-[a-zA-Z]+$/,"");print}'  Input_file
```

Comment: This will fail in case the file contains a pattern like `|NonNumeric-Combo`.   Also using ODD position logic is an overkill for this task and will cause unnecessary overheads. Why this logic when UNIX has given us super powers like character classes , regex ?

Comment: Added one more solution using substitute functionality on same.

Comment: Failing again for input `53-Brand|5556-Color Family|10984-Fit|10313-Combo|meow-bhow`.  Giving output as `53,5556,10984,10313,meow`. I recommend you to capture digits as suggested in my last comment.

Comment: ok, will try to make more generic. but I think I given fair warning that if Input_file is same as sample shown, this is written keeping that I mind only.

Comment: Yeah makes sense. My only concern was since only digits needs to be extracted so all this is really not required and could be done straightforwardly without any additional overhead.

Answer (score 1):

Using `gensub()` running by default on the current line, is most likely the
most elegant solution:

```
awk '{ print gensub(/-[^|]+\|?/, " ", "g"); }' tmp.txt
```

The regular expression `/-[^|]+\|/` matches anything starting with `-` 
until the optional `|` (which does not appear at the end of line).

Comment: You should mention that's gawk-only due to `gensub()`.

Comment: @EdMorton agreed.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your one-line-data-file is `input.txt`, you can basically achieve what you want by

```
tr -cs  '|0-9' ' ' <input.txt | tr  '|' ,
```

The first `tr` produces the spaces, the second one produces the commas.

However you need to be aware that this outputs no \n at the end. Depending on what you want to do with the result, this might or might not what you want to have. If a trailing newline is importand, you can do for instance

```
tr -cs  '|0-9' ' ' <input.txt | tr  '|' , ; echo
```

or the less performant

```
tr -cs  '|0-9' ' ' <input.txt | tr  '|' , | xargs
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "53-Brand|5556-Color Family|10984-Fit|10313-Combo"|awk -F'[-|]' '{print $1","$3","$5","$7}'

53,5556,10984,10313
```

Comment: could you add a description?

Comment: @ExDev that's like asking someone who writes `i++` to add a comment describing what that does. Not all answers need a description.

Comment: @EdMorton: I have no knowledge about that and you could be right but, if it's so trivial, I can suppose the OP will needs an explanation, otherwise I think he would have answered by himself

Comment: Not at all. Not being able to come up with the exact syntax to do something trivial doesn't mean you can't understand trivial code when it's shown to you. And if you CAN'T understand trivial code then its much better for you to learn how to look up a couple of basic constructs  in the man page than have it spoon-fed to you. When the tool flags an answer as possibly low quality due to lack of text it's up to the reviewers to decide if the answer is low quality or not, don't just assume the tool is correct - if the tool was always right it wouldn't just raise a flag for a person to review.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -F'[-|]' '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i+=2) print $i}' file
53
5556
10984
10313
```

Most answers you've got so far will fail if/when a digit appears in the text you do not want printed or if/when a non-digit appears in the text you do want printed, the above won't. For example with `Brand7` instead of `Brand` and `53A` instead of `53`:

```
$ echo '53A-Brand7|5556-Color Family|10984-Fit|10313-Combo' | awk -F'[-|]' '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i+=2) print $i}'
53A
5556
10984
10313
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your input data I see it is nicely chunked by two delimiters ... first the pipe char | and then by char -  ... 
this preliminary first step splits the string on delimiter '|'

```
echo "53-Brand|5556-Color Family|10984-Fit|10313-Combo" |  xargs -d'|' -i  echo {}
53-Brand
5556-Color Family
10984-Fit
10313-Combo
```

and for full solution this splits each substring which is now on its own line by delimiter '-'

```
echo "53-Brand|5556-Color Family|10984-Fit|10313-Combo"|xargs -d'|' -i  echo {}|cut -d '-' -f1
53
5556
10984
10313
```